# eclipse crashes when debug with PyDev

Tags: eclipse, pydev

Just as described in the title. I am using Eclipse Helios, PyDev plugin 2.2.2.2022082312, the OS is Red Hat 4.1.2-48 Linux version 2.6.18-194.el5. After I set the breakpoint and start to debug, Eclipse always crashes.

Comment: Meh, there are times that Eclipse crashes just by looking at its window... ;-)

Comment: Can you post log of the error ?

Answer (score 1):

Check out log file under $eclipse/configuration folder or analyse the dump files using tools like http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cn/websphere/library/techarticles/0903_suipf_javadump/

Maybe you can get more useful information from that. Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

If you have a crash (i.e.: the vm quits creating a dump), it's almost always a bug in the Java VM. So, try using a different VM -- usually the most reliable is the Sun Java VM -- or maybe it's called Oracle Java VM now :)